# Catch OptimizeWarning as an exception

Tags: python, exception, scipy, warnings

I was just trying to catch an `OptimizeWarning` thrown by the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` function, but I realized it was not recognized as a valid exception.

This is a non-working simple idea of what I'm doing:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
try:
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(some parameters)
except OptimizeWarning:
    print 'Maxed out calls.'
    # do something
```

I looked around [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/search.html?q=OptimizeWarning&check_keywords=yes&area=default) but there was nothing there.

Am I missing something obvious or is it simply not defined for some reason?

BTW, this is the full warning I get and that I want to catch:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:604: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can require that Python raise this warning as an exception using the following code:

```
import warnings
from scipy.optimize import OptimizeWarning

warnings.simplefilter("error", OptimizeWarning)
# Your code here
```

## Issues with warnings

Unfortunately, `warnings` in Python have a few issues you need to be aware of.

### Multiple filters

First, there can be multiple filters, so your warning filter can be overridden by something else. This is not too bad and can be worked around with the `catch_warnings` context manager:

```
import warnings
from scipy.optimize import OptimizeWarning

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("error", OptimizeWarning)
    try:
        # Do your thing 
    except OptimizeWarning:
        # Do your other thing
```

### Raised Once

Second, warnings are only raised once by default. If your warning has already been raised before you set the filter, you can change the filter, it won't raise the warning again.

To my knowledge, there unfortunately is not much you can do about this. You'll want to make sure you run the `warnings.simplefilter("error", OptimizeWarning)` as early as possible.

Comment: This seems to work if I just use `warnings.simplefilter("error")`, using the full line `warnings.simplefilter("error", OptimizeWarning)` results in: `NameError: global name 'OptimizeWarning' is not defined`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Gabriel That's because you need to import `OptimizeWarning` first (you need to do that to use it in an `except` clause anyway): `from scipy.optimize import OptimizeWarning`. Updated my answer to clarify this.